Would the video ports be useable on AM5 board with EPYC?
Would videoports be useable on
AsRock Rack B650D4U Micro-ATX Server Motherboard Single Socket AMD EPYC™ 4004 and AMD Ryzen™ 8000/7000 series Processors (LGA 1718) B650E PCIe 5.0 Dual 1G Lan, when I use EPYC 4004 or do I need to buy a videocard?
